# Why I am getting an input shape error after I specified the input shape?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to train a CNN in anaconda, jupyter notebook. The TensorFlow version is 1.14. And I am experimenting the mobilenet_v2. Here is my code:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
base_model=tf.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2.MobileNetV2(include_top=False,weights=None,input_shape=(150,150,3))
x = base_model.output
x = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
predictions = tf.keras.layers.Dense(9,activation='softmax')(x)
model = Model(inputs = base_model.input,outputs=predictions)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=["accuracy"],optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam())
history = model.fit(train_data,
                   epochs=5,steps_per_epoch=len(train_data),
                   validation_steps=0.2*len(train_data))
```

The input shape of the images is 150x150x3, and I double-checked the input image size to ensure it is correct.
[image size of a random image from imagedata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrizh.png)

After I fit the model, I got an error said( Error when checking input: expected input_8 to have shape (150, 150, 3) but got array with shape (256, 256, 3)    )
[error message screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0cjD.png)

Here is a screenshot of the model summary; the inputlayer has the correct shape, so I am not sure where the 256 comes from.
[first few layers of the model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RPxV.png)

ps: I also tried to build a custom model with just a few layers, but the same error still occurred:

```
custom_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(10,10,activation='relu',input_shape=(150,150,3)),
tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(),
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(10,10,activation='relu'),
tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(),
tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(9,activation='softmax')
])
custom_model.summary()
custom_model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",
        optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
        metrics=["accuracy"])
custom_model_history = custom_model.fit(train_data,
              epochs=5,
              steps_per_epoch=len(train_data),
              validation_data=val_data,
              validation_steps=len(val_data))
```

Here is the summary of the custom model: [custom model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mdMc.png)
And here is the error message: [error message from custom model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUPDO.png)

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but `validation_steps` is relevant only if `validation_data` is provided and is a `tf.data` dataset. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model

Answer (score 0):

please look into your train, test splits (look into this example)

```
num_classes = 10
input_shape = (28, 28, 1)
```

## Load the data and split it between train and test sets

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
```

## Scale images to the [0, 1] range

```
x_train = x_train.astype("float32") / 255
x_test = x_test.astype("float32") / 255
# Make sure images have shape (28, 28, 1)
x_train = np.expand_dims(x_train, -1)
x_test = np.expand_dims(x_test, -1)
print("x_train shape:", x_train.shape)
print(x_train.shape[0], "train samples")
print(x_test.shape[0], "test samples")
```

## convert class vectors to binary class matrices

```
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)
```

## also while training you have to mention both x and y in your training data

i think you didn't  mentioned x_train and y_train instead of that you mentioned only x_train

```
batch_size = 128
epochs = 15
custom_model_history = custom_model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, validation_split=0.1)
```